# Is there an equivalent class to UIView in WatchKit?

Tags: uiview, watchkit, apple-watch

I have an iOS app that dynamically draw shapes on UIView (through drawRect), and I am looking at the possibility to port that app (or a small part of that) to Apple Watch. Unfortunately, after read through relative posts I cannot find which class can handle the similar job in WatchKit.

So the question is:

1. If there is a similar class like UIView, in WatchKit, to draw lines cycles on Apple Watch?
2. What is the best (possible) way to implement a simple drawing function on Apple Watch, if there is no UIView like class. (Assume this is achievable)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, there is no class similar to `UIView` in WatchKit
2. You can generate images and transfer them to Watch App using `WKInterfaceImage`'s `func setImage(image: UIImage?)`

   - If you already have drawing code for drawing in `-drawRect:`, it shouldn't be that difficult to modify it to support drawing to image

Comment: Lovely! Originally the frame rate would be 20 fps, hopefully the Apple Watch can handle 20 images within a second. I will try that anyway.